# JSON сборка как сделать?

Tags: c#

Как мне тут поступить? умею на данный момент такую запись

```
{
  "name": "null",
  "Ip": "null",
}
```

Но мне нужно такого вида

```
{
  "Тут ID пользователя"
  {
     "name": "null",
     "Ip": "null",
  }
}
```

И так под каждого нового пользователя - вот как я добавляю json в файл

```
internal static void Serialize<T>(this T arg, string fileName)
    {
        string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, res);
    }

    internal static T Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        T res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Текст

```
{
  "Тут ID пользователя"
  {
     "name": "null",
     "Ip": "null",
  }
}
```

не является валидным JSON'ом, так что такой текст вы получить не сможете.

Возможно, вам подойдёт

```
{
  "Тут ID пользователя" : {
     "name": "null",
     "Ip": "null",
  }
}
```

который получается при помощи такого кода:

```
internal static void Serialize<T>(this T arg, string id, string fileName)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, T>() { [id] = arg };
    string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, res);
}
```

Соответственно меняется и процедура десериализации.

```
internal static (T, string) Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    Dictionary<string, T> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);
    string id = res.Keys.Single();
    T value = res[id];
    return (value, id);
}
```

Comment: @Нет - данный способ не подходит - получаю у себя краш - может есть котовый парсер?

Comment: @Azymok: Ну поймайте исключение через try/catch и посмотрите в отладчике, какой там текст исключения.

Comment: если вернуть мои старые значения за место тех,что вы мне предложили с PasteBin то все работает - правда не настроенна Deserialize

Comment: @Azymok: Значит, ошибка где-то ещё, ищите. Посмотрите, например, сюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64142/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-json---).